# What do these logos mean - UK and IE inside a circle

Tags: logo

[image]

What do the symbols UK and IE inside a circle mean?

Comment: I'm in the UK and I'm not 100% sure. Are there ingredients in other languages? If so it normally indicates the language.

Comment: What does this have to do with graphic design?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't deal with graphic design

Answer (score 1):

I'm with CAI on this, they usually indicate which language(s) the label is written in.

**UK** would normally indicate Ukranian.  I'm assuming they mis-labeled this packaging, intentionally or not, and used it to represent English, as spoken in the UK. English *should* be represented with EN

**IE** indicates the [Interlingue or Occidental language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occidental_language)

You can see a full list of 2 letter language codes [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes), under the 639-1 column.

**Edit**
These can also stand for countries, instead of languages - UK = United Kingdom, IE = Ireland (except the North, which is still part of the UK).

Comment: I just went to my kitchen to double check and it is definitely languages.. From what I've seen the language codes normally follow [these ISO codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2). The United Kingdom is *usually* labelled as GB but its not uncommon for it to be listed as UK. 'IE' is actually Ireland.

Comment: "The European Commission generally uses ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 codes with two exceptions: EL (not GR) is used to represent Greece, and UK (not GB) is used to represent the United Kingdom."

Comment: I got ya.  I was looking at languages, rather than countries, that's probably why the codes I came across differed from the ones you provided @CAI